# Suddenly very slow Wireless Connection (Ubuntu 14.04) after one year without trouble

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

My Title says it all.
This started just a couple days ago. Before this, I had not had any trouble during the last year of daily use. I began using 14.04 in summer 2014.

I checked similar questions already asked on this website, and it's difficult for me to understand the answers. The chief difference between my situation and others is that i know nothing about coding. This would be the first time i ever attempt any commands. Am i biting off more than i can chew? There is a very nice group of "Free Geeks" in my city, and they volunteer help on some nights. Would i better off handling it that way?

Thanking you in advance for any advice and help you can offer.

Best Regards

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/641809/edit) your question, to add more info.  Have you installed any new applications?  Have you done any updates? Have you removed any applications? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, some new apps: skype, audacity, VLC player, netflicks. But nothing recently. Updates have been done regularly as i get prompted. Nothing removed by me. No error message.